# spring JasperException JSTL tags

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

**Code block causing the JSTL error:**

```
<c:when test="${(list.IS_SECRET_YN eq 'Y' && (session.USER_TYPE eq null || session.USER_TYPE ne 'A' ))) }">
```

**This is the error I face:**

```
**9월 15, 2014 11:29:50 오전 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
심각: Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/pages/main/service/qna.jsp(84,19) "${(list.IS_SECRET_YN eq 'Y' && (session.USER_TYPE eq null || session.USER_TYPE ne 'A' ))) }" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${(list.IS_SECRET_YN eq 'Y' && (session.USER_TYPE eq null || session.USER_TYPE ne 'A' ))) }]**
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1187)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:847)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:866)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:866)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:866)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2417)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1782)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:653)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:647)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.template.layout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(layout_jsp.java:151)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.template.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:86)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

there is `elExcepiont` so i thougth it's jstl error
but i don't know what is wrong code exactly

i'm using spring framework with java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misplaced braces here ,

```
<c:when test="${(list.IS_SECRET_YN eq 'Y' && (session.USER_TYPE eq null || session.USER_TYPE ne 'A' ))) }">
```

On removing,

```
    <c:when test="${(list.IS_SECRET_YN eq 'Y' && 
       (session.USER_TYPE eq null || session.USER_TYPE ne 'A' ))}">
    </c:when>
```

**NOTE :** If you are trying to access the variables from session , use `sessionScope.varName` to get their values .

Hope this helps !!